# C# - backgroundworker wait for file to be created

Tags: c#, file-io, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker..
In the backgroundworker_doWork
I would like to check if a file exists or not.. if doesn't then i wait for the file to be create and once its create then carry on with the work its suppose to do

I want do something like this.. but i just figure out how to do it.. im new to this :

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if(File.Exists(filename)){
        //.. code to do my work ...
    }
    else{
        //..Wait for the file to be create...
    }
//... end of backgroundworker
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to get an event when the file is created.

Comment: Because the scenario is that, the file exists for a while then another process deletes it.. so i have to get back to a state of checking if the file is deleted.. a snippet or something of that sort would be really helpful

Comment: The `FileSystemWatcher` has multiple events: For creation and for deletion. I suggest you read the manual and with that knowledge try to change your algorithm for handling the file.

Answer (score 3):

You should really use a `FileSystemWatcher`. For "waiting tasks", `BackgroundWorker` is not the right tool - I'd use `FileSystemWatcher` or a traditional thread.